# See Byobu Screens using ConnectBot

Tags: ssh, android, byobu

I use ConnectBot sometimes to connect to my ubuntu machine, and that works fine, however it just comes up with a standard shell, not my byobu screens that I get when I connect to it using another machine running ssh, such as my windows machine running PuTTy.

Is there any way that I can see my byobu screens from ConnectBot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ConnectBot sets `$TERM` to `screen`, instead of `xterm` like most terminal emulators. Because of that, Byobu thinks it's being run inside *another* Byobu or screen, and doesn't launch.

To solve, go to ConnectBot preferences, and set Emulation Mode to `xterm` instead of `screen`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work. Wish I thought of this before. I did find [a workaround](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/65977/50681) though. `screen -r -d` worked in my case.